# PostgreSQL join subquery can't restrict query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

**MOVED THIS QUESTION OVER TO DBA STACKEXCHANGE:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137878/postgresql-join-subquery-cant-restrict-query**

I'm working on a check-splitting project that splits out amount owed for an activity. Users can be apart of multiple 'groups', which each have their own running balances.

I'm trying to run a query that will return an individual users 'amount owed' across all groups.

At the moment the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(owe) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (expenses.amount/count(*))
    AS owe 
    FROM expenses 
    LEFT JOIN user_expenses 
    ON (
        expenses.id = user_expenses.expense_id
        ) 
    WHERE expenses.paid_by != 1 
    GROUP BY expenses.id
    ) 
AS total;
```

The problem is this query retrieves ALL expenses across the board. What i'd like to do is restrict by using:

```
WHERE user_expenses.user_id = 1
```

How can I add that to the aforementioned query (in a subquery) to restrict the result to expenses that only that user is associated with?

TABLE SCHEMA (if that might help):

```
USERS
id
name
username
email

EXPENSES
id
created_at
updated_at
title
amount
group_id
paid_by
img_url
note

USER_EXPENSES (join table)
id
expense_id
user_id

GROUPS
id
created_at
name
desc

USER_GROUPS
id
user_id
group_id
```

Some more sample info for clarification:
if i run this query -

```
SELECT 
    e.title,
    e.amount,
    (e.amount/count(*)) AS owe, count(*) AS members 
      FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN
           user_expenses ue
           ON e.id = ue.expense_id
      WHERE e.paid_by != 1 
      GROUP BY e.id;
```

i get something like this (with dummy data):
[image]

If I run the following:

```
SELECT 
    e.title,
    e.amount,
    (e.amount/count(*)) AS owe, count(*) AS members 
      FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN
           user_expenses ue
           ON e.id = ue.expense_id AND ue.user_id = 1
      WHERE e.paid_by != 1 
      GROUP BY e.id;
```

I get this (note the members count):
[image]

Comment: The critical piece I keep running up against when setting a condition on user_expense.user_id is I need all members from an expense to return so that I can divide a shared expense as seen on the 5th line:
`(e.amount/count(*))`
Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with two solutions. One thanks to an amazing team member who powered through it and made something that works and one that could be considered a bit less expensive. Thanks to both nonetheless.

Turns out HAVING was the critical part for getting the desired solution (thanks @andriy-m):

> HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions

```
SELECT SUM(owe) 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (e.amount/count(*)) AS owe 
  FROM expenses e 
  LEFT JOIN
       user_expenses ue
  ON e.id = ue.expense_id
  WHERE e.paid_by != 1 
  GROUP BY e.id
  HAVING COUNT(ue.user_id = 1 OR NULL) > 0
) 
AS total;
```

ALSO, in honor of PJ who worked hard on this:

```
SELECT SUM(owe) 
FROM (SELECT (expenses.amount/count(*)) AS owe 
FROM expenses 
LEFT JOIN user_expenses ON (expenses.id = user_expenses.expense_id) 
WHERE expenses.paid_by != 1 
AND expense_id IN (select expense_id from users LEFT JOIN user_expenses 
ON (1 = user_expenses.user_id)) GROUP BY expenses.id)
AS total;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query works, then you would just add this to the subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(owe) 
FROM (SELECT (e.amount/count(*)) AS owe 
      FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN
           user_expenses ue
           ON e.id = ue.expense_id AND ue.user_id = 1
      WHERE expenses.paid_by <> 1 
      GROUP BY expenses.id
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @gordon-linoff. I updated your suggestion on the last two lines (replaced expenses with alias 'e') and the query returns all expenses - not just the ones associated with the user. Any other thoughts?

updated query:
`SELECT e.title,e.amount,(e.amount/count(*)) AS owe 
      FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN
           user_expenses ue
           ON e.id = ue.expense_id AND ue.user_id = 1
      WHERE e.paid_by != 1 
      GROUP BY e.id;
`

Comment: further clarification:
using that additional condition you suggested, means the `(e.amount/count(*))` doesn't run correctly. that piece returns an expense divided by the number of people involved in that expense.

Comment: Would it make sense to add yet another subquery in the WHERE ?